# Report (unique, totals) creation from events in table

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, events, event-handling

in simplified terms, have a table of event data -
event_id, customer_id, type, status(NEW, PROCESSED)
From this data, I want to create a report for each event_id, so basically I want to group the numbers. The report should contain totals for the type - as well unique numbers for the type.

There are hundreds of customers, and for each customer, hunreds of those reports must be created - so I guess it's best to not create them on the fly, but pre-process the reports.

The problem however is that these are also events, that keep coming in (potentially forever, realistically most during the first 24 hours, and after 3 month there won't be much activity most likely.

So I am thinking of 2 strategies - either, I process each record once, and put it from NEW to PROCESSED then. The reports would be written into its own table. For the total numbers, that's relatively easy, I would just add the new numbers to the existing numbers of the report. For the unique numbers however - that's rather complex - I would need to find out if there already exists the same event_id, customer_id, type with status=PROCESSED
or I would have to do a group by and calculate ALL reports all over again I guess?
Plus, while going through the entries in status=NEW, I would have to update them to status=PROCESSED when done..so in a stream iterating and updating one table, while updating the reports in the other table (and all this with Hibernate and a scrollable result set...)

Sorry... EOD and deep down in my rabbit hole... hope this makes any sense to you ;). Any hints appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the issue. Just regenerate these reports when needed. Doesn't sound like this should take longer than a few milliseconds when you have proper indexes, but then you didn't specify what your requirement is or provide details like a query that you are trying to execute, so it's hard to say what is appropriate.